# Multi-GPU Peer-to-Peer Slow between Particular Pairs

Tags: deep-learning, gpu, nvidia, multi-gpu

I have 8 RTX GPUs. When run `p2pBandwidthLatencyTest`, The latencies between GPU0 and GPU1, GPU2 and GPU3, GPU4 and GPU5, GPU6 and GPU7 is 40,000 times slower than other pairs:

```
P2P=Enabled Latency (P2P Writes) Matrix (us)
   GPU     0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7 
     0   1.80 49354.72   1.70   1.70   1.74   1.74   1.74   1.72 
     1 49354.84   1.37   1.70   1.69   1.74   1.76   1.73   1.72 
     2   1.88   1.81   1.73 49355.00   1.79   1.76   1.76   1.75 
     3   1.88   1.79 49354.85   1.33   3.79   3.84   3.88   3.91 
     4   1.89   1.88   1.90   1.87   1.72 49354.96   3.49   3.56 
     5   2.30   1.93   1.88   1.89 49354.89   1.32   3.63   3.60 
     6   2.55   2.53   2.37   2.29   2.24   2.26   3.50 49354.77 
     7   2.30   2.27   2.29   1.87   1.82   1.83 49354.85   1.36
```

Compare it with when peer-to-peer is disabled:

```
P2P=Disabled Latency Matrix (us)
   GPU     0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7 
     0   1.80  14.31  13.86  13.49  14.52  13.89  13.58  13.58 
     1  13.71   1.82  14.44  13.95  14.65  13.62  15.05  15.20 
     2  13.38  14.23   1.73  16.59  13.77  15.44  14.10  13.64 
     3  12.68  15.62  12.50   1.77  14.92  15.01  15.17  14.87 
     4  13.51  13.60  15.09  13.40   1.27  12.48  12.68  19.47 
     5  14.92  13.84  13.42  13.42  16.53   1.30  16.37  16.60 
     6  14.29  13.62  14.66  13.62  14.90  13.70   1.32  14.33 
     7  14.26  13.42  14.35  13.53  16.89  14.26  17.03   1.36
```

Is this normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the super slow peer-to-peer is *abnormal*.

**After I disable IOMMU (Intel VT-d) in the BIOS, the problem is gone**:

```
P2P=Enabled Latency (P2P Writes) Matrix (us)
   GPU     0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7 
     0   1.34   1.22   1.68   1.69   1.71   1.70   1.75   1.73 
     1   1.20   1.38   1.70   1.67   1.71   1.75   1.75   1.72 
     2   1.69   1.67   1.29   1.20   1.73   1.75   1.75   1.75 
     3   1.69   1.66   1.17   1.29   1.74   1.75   1.72   1.73 
     4   1.72   1.76   1.74   1.70   1.32   1.13   1.66   1.70 
     5   1.74   1.73   1.75   1.74   1.18   1.28   1.67   1.69 
     6   1.75   1.74   1.74   1.72   1.67   1.68   1.31   1.19 
     7   1.76   1.75   1.73   1.73   1.67   1.69   1.18   1.32
```

It seems the problem is the same as or is very similar to discussions in:

- https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1637
- https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/24081

A few possible solutions are mentioned in the discussions:

Disable IOMMU:

- https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1637#issuecomment-338268158
- https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1637#issuecomment-401422046

Disable ACS:

- https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/24081#issuecomment-557074611
- https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/24081#issuecomment-547976127

My system having the problem only had IOMMU enabled in the BIOS. ACS was not turned on as `lspci -vvv | grep ACS` got back nothing.

==============================

Background on I/O MMU:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#I/O_MMU_virtualization_(AMD-Vi_and_Intel_VT-d)

It's part of the x86 virtualization. It's the virtualization done by the chipset. Besides the name IOMMU, it's also called AMD-Vi or Intel VT-d. Not to be confused with AMD-V and Intel VT-x which are virtualization via the CPU.